# Web scraping on aws lambda with cheerio and axios

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, aws-lambda, axios, cheerio

I am trying to build a web scrapper with axios and cheerio on aws. My function worked on my local host. But I can't scrape the website on AWS Lambda.

```
const  axios = require("axios")
const cheerio = require("cheerio")

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    
    const URL = 'https://bscscan.com/token/tokenholderchart/0x965f527d9159dce6288a2219db51fc6eef120dd1?range=10'
        var articles = []
        async function getThePercentage(){
            await axios(URL).then(res => {
        const htmlData = res.data
        const $ = cheerio.load(htmlData)
                
        
        $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_resultrows > table > tbody > tr', htmlData).each((index, element) => {
            let title = $(element).children('td:nth-child(4)').text().slice(0, -1)
            articles.push(title)
        })
        
        }).catch(err => console.error(err))

        
        let sum = articles.map(Number)
        return sum.reduce((a,b) => (a+b), 0)
        
    }

   
    
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: getThePercentage()
    };

    
    return response
};
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 1):

In your response object you're missing the await when calling the getThePercentage() as it is an async function, so you're returning a promise and not the result of the function.

Fixed:

```
const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: await getThePercentage()
};
```

This should work.